# Vector erase giving unexpected result

Tags: algorithm, c++11, stl

Erase from vector giving different results with lambda function and function object.

I'm trying to delete 3rd element from a vector of strings. 
With function object 3rd and 6th element is getting deleted but with lambda version the code gives expected result.

I tried following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include<algorithm>
#include<iterator>
#include<vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

vector<string> s;

copy(istream_iterator<string>(cin),
    istream_iterator<string>(),
    back_inserter(s));

    cout<<"S contains :"<<endl;
    for(auto x:s)
        cout<<x<<" ";
    cout<<endl;

#ifndef USE_LAMBDA    

struct Word_No{
int word_ith;
int word_count;

Word_No(int x)  :word_ith(x),word_count(0){}

bool operator () (string){
return ++word_count == word_ith;
}
};
//3rd Element remove
    s.erase(remove_if(s.begin(),s.end(),Word_No(3)),s.end());
#else
    int count =0;
    s.erase(remove_if(s.begin(),
                      s.end(),
                      [&count](string){
                         return ++count ==3; //3rd Element Remove
                            }),
                      s.end());
#endif

    cout<<"Now S contains :"<<endl;
    for(auto x:s)
        cout<<x<<" ";
}
```

**Results:**

> g++ -o test test.cpp -std=gnu++0x
>
> Input: King Queen Jack Ace Rook
>   Knight Pawn Bishop
>
> Output:
>
> S contains : King Queen Jack Ace Rook Knight Pawn Bishop
>
> Now S contains : King Queen Ace Rook Pawn Bishop **//Wrong Result 3 and 6th element deleted.**
>
> g++ -o test test.cpp -std=gnu++0x -DUSE_LAMBDA
>
> Input: King Queen Jack Ace Rook Knight Pawn Bishop
>
> S contains : King Queen Jack Ace Rook Knight Pawn Bishop
>
> Now S contains : King Queen Ace Rook Knight Pawn Bishop  ***// Correct Result***

Could anyone please explain these two behaviors ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're a victim of `remove_if` implementation, Josuttis's The C++ Standard Library describes this in detail.

The summary is:

The 3rd and 6th Element is removed for without lambda version because `remove_if` copies the predicate internally during processing.

It uses `find_if` internally to find the element that should be removed.
Later the algorithm uses a copy of the predicate to process the remaining elements, if any, using `remove_if_copy`

In case of lambda, as you're passing argument by reference, lambda object internally used by
`remove_if` share same state

This is the approximate implementation of remove_if

```
template<typename FwdItr, typename Pred>
FwdItr std::remove_if(FwdItr b, FwdItr e, Pred f)
{
    s = find_if(b,e,f);
    if(s==e)
        return b;
    else
     {
        FwdItr temp = b;
        return remove_copy_if(++temp, e, b, f);
     }
}
```

Comment: +1.  As a conforming extension, libc++ (http://libcxx.llvm.org) gets the right answer both with and without `-DUSE_LAMBDA`.  This (no internal functor copies) is also true for all other algorithms in libc++.  It doesn't take much more effort to implement it with this conforming extension.

Comment: @P0W Is it possible to re-create same scenario with lambda function ?

Comment: @user1446258 yes make lambda function `mutable`

Answer (score 2):

The standard definition doesn't say that this function will use the predicate in a specific order, what it says is:

> 1 Requires: The type of *first shall satisfy the MoveAssignable
>   requirements (Table 22).
>
> 2 Effects: Eliminates all the elements referred to by iterator i in
>   the range [first,last) for which the following corresponding
>   conditions hold: *i == value, pred(*i) != false.
>
> 3 Returns: The end of the resulting range.
>
> 4 Remarks: Stable (17.6.5.7).
>
> 5 Complexity: Exactly last - first applications of the corresponding
>   predicate.
>
> 6 Note: each element in the range [ret,last), where ret is the
>   returned value, has a valid but unspecified state, because the
>   algorithms can eliminate elements by moving from elements that were
>   originally in that range.

Therefore you should not assume that the predicate will be used in the same order that elements of the vector are.

Finally, you could simply write

```
..
s.erase(s.begin()+2);
..
```

to erase the third element of the vector.

best regards